Vite React "use client" sourcemap warning
I have turborepo with React (Vite) and NextJS and shared components located in workspace. I have set it to use server components, but because of that Vite writes warning on build:
../../packages/ui/src/components/ui/alert-dialog.tsx (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error. ../../packages/ui/src/components/ui/dropdown-menu.tsx (1:0): Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
Any way to make Vite ignore "use client" and "use server"?
Tried to setup tsconfig, and set sourcemap: true in vite.config.ts

Found solution is to write plugin that removes "use client":
function removeUseClient() {
  const filter = createFilter(/.*\.(js|ts|jsx|tsx)$/);

  return {
    name: 'remove-use-client',

    transform(code: string, id: string) {
      if (!filter(id)) {
        return null;
      }

      const newCode = code.replace(/['"]use client['"];\s*/g, '');

      return  { code: newCode, map: null };
    },
  };
}

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    removeUseClient()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@src', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, './src') },
      { find: '@ui', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../packages/ui/src') }
    ]
  }
});

